# If $\Bbb R$ means all real number, then what does $\Bbb R^2$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am sort of baffled by this thing, already real number has every thing in it why is this concept of $\Bbb R^2$ ? What does it mean? What is its advantage?

Answer (score 6):

$\Bbb R$ is the set of real numbers. That is, $\Bbb R=\{x:\text{$x$ is a real number}\}$.

$\Bbb R^2$ is the set of pairs of real numbers. That is, $\Bbb R^2=\Bbb R\times\Bbb R=\{(x,y):\text{$x$ and $y$ are real numbers}\}$.

Answer (score 3):

We usually use $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, to refer to what we picture as the number line.

Thus, $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set of pairs of real numbers, is what we picture as the $xy$-plane, coordinatized by two number lines.

If you want to talk about space with $n$ dimensions, then you want a "copy" of $\mathbb{R}$ for each dimension, to give you independent coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

the Cartesian product of the reals with itself is a common meaning.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb R $ doesn't have everything. For example, it doesn't have an $x $ such that $x^2 = -1$. The complex numbers contain such objects.

$\mathbb R^2$ can be used for a lot of things. The most obvious is to describe points in a plane.